# Cloud Run Container Failed To Start

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-run

I am using Cloud Run and I got an error when deploying to Cloud Run. It says Container failed to start.

Node.js Version: 16.13.2

Error:

```
/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/../node/bin/node: 1: /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/../node/bin/node: This: not found
```

Docker File:

```
FROM node:16-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY . .
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "something-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "something-description",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "JacTBB",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^5.0.2",
    "discord-webhook-node": "^1.1.8",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.5.1",
    "noblox.js": "^4.12.0",
    "node": "^16.3.2",
    "node-fetch-npm": "^2.0.4",
    "npm": "^8.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Editted it in.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted my node_modules folder and reinstalled everything. Works now.